# High order Function not taking right parameter

Tags: haskell, parameters, higher-order-functions

I have an exercise to make a higher order function in haskell which takes another func I created.

```
multiplyFive :: [Int] -> [Int]
multiplyFive [] = []
multiplyFive (x:xs) = (x * 5) : multiplyFive xs
```

then I create this funct to add all the numbers that is in the list given

```
addAll :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> Int
addAll fn [] = 0
addAll fn (x:xs) = x + addAll fn xs
```

I am trying to do this

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
    print(addAll multiplyFive [1..4])
```

The output should be 50 but it gives me an output of 10

Comment: You don't use `fn` in `addAll` except for passing it to the next call

Comment: @cafce25 if I do that when I try to do print(addAll multiplyFive [1..4]) it shows me this error: Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
  Expected: Int -> Int
    Actual: [Int] -> [Int]
• In the first argument of ‘addAll’, namely ‘multiplyFive’
  In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
    ‘(addAll multiplyFive [1 .. 4])’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (addAll multiplyFive [1 .. 4])typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)

Comment: The error means that the way you're using `fn` in `addAll`, `multiplyFive` should have the signature `Int -> Int` ie it shouldn't take a list and produce one but just take an integer and produce one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only *pass* `fn` to recursive calls, you don't *use* `fn` to apply this on elements. The `addAll` thus should be:

```
addAll :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> Int
addAll fn xs = go (fn xs)
  where go [] = 0
        go (x : xs) = x + go xs
```

the function can however be simplified to:

```
addAll :: (Foldable f, Num b) => (a -> f b) -> a -> b
addAll = (sum .)
```

and `multiplyFive` is just:

```
multiplyFive :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
multiplyFive = map (5 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. Can be the function addAll polymorphic?

Comment: @diegog: `addAll` is polymorphic.